# no consigo enviar el formulario

Tags: php, javascript, formularios

Tengo un validación hecha con JS; y quisiera saber como conjugarla con el envío de un formulario mediante PHP.

Al introducir el código PHP que vi resuelto en otra pregunta, veo que existe una duplicidad, ya que tengo un condicional con return true y false. ¿Como se conjuga con este código de PHP?Lo subo  a mi servidor que es de 1&1 y no funciona.

```css
<?php

// Declaración de variables del formulario

 $nombre = $_POST('nombre');
 $telefono = $_POST('telefono');
 $email = $_POST('email');
 $adultos = $_POST('adultos');
 $infantes = $_POST('infantes');
 $total= $_POST('total');
 $perros= $_POST('perros');
 $mensaje= $_POST('mensaje');
    $fechaEntrada= $_POST('fechaEntrada');
    $fechaSalida= $_POST('fechaSalida');
    



// Datos del email
$para = 'elcallejondelagata@gmail.com';
$titulo = 'Solicitud de información';
$header = 'From: ' . $email;
$msjCorreo = "Nombre:".$nombre."\n".
     "Email: ".$email."\n".
     "Telefono: ".$telefono."\n".
     "Numero de adultos: ".$adultos."\n".
     "Numero de niños: ".$infantes."\n".
     "Total de personas: ".$total."\n".
     "Perros: ".$perros."\n".
     "Fecha de entrada: ".$fechaEntrada."\n".
     "Fecha de salida: ".$fechaSalida."\n";


if ($_POST['enviar']) {

    if (mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header)) {

    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias por contactar con nosotros.');
    </script>";
    } else {
        echo 'Falló el envio';
    }
}

?>
```

```js
function validacion() {

  let nombre = document.getElementById("campoNombre").value;
  let telefono = document.getElementById("campoTelefono").value;
  let email = document.getElementById("campoEmail").value;
  let adultos = document.getElementById("numeroAdultos").value;
  let ninhos = document.getElementById("numeroInfantes").value;
  let perros = document.getElementById("numeroPerros").value;
  let mensaje = document.getElementById("campoMensaje").value;
  let politicaDatos = document.getElementById("politica").checked;
  let entrada = document.getElementById("fechaEnt").value;
  let salida = document.getElementById("fechaSal").value;

  if (nombre === null || telefono === null  ||  email === null || adultos === null || ninhos === null || perros === null || mensaje === null || entrada === null || salida === null) {

            msg("No se enviaron los datos. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo");
            return false;

      } else {

            if (/^\s+$/.test(nombre) ||  nombre.length < 2 || /[0-9]/.test(nombre)) {

                  msg("El campo 'Nombre' no es correcto. Es obligatorio, de mínimo 2 letras y no puede contener números.", 5000);
                  return false;
            }

            else if (!/^\d{9}$/.test(telefono)) {

                  msg("El campo 'Teléfono' no es correcto. Es obligatorio, y el formato debe ser 000000000", 5000);
                  return false;

            }


            else if (!/^\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{2,4}$/.test(entrada) ) {

                  msg("La fecha no es correcta");
                  return false;

            }

            else if (!/^\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{2,4}$/.test(salida) ) {

                  msg("La fecha no es correcta");
                  return false;

            }



            else if ( email.length === 0 || email.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.indexOf(".") < 1 ){

                  msg("El campo 'Email' no es correcto. Es obligatorio, y debes indicar una '@' y un '.'");
                  return false;

            }

            

            else if (!/^\d{1,2}$/.test(adultos)) {

                  msg("El campo 'número de Adultos' es obligatorio", 5000);
                  return false;

            }

            else if (!/^\d{0,2}$/.test(ninhos)) {

                  msg("El campo 'número de niños' es obligatorio", 5000);
                  return false;

            }

            else if (!/^\d{0,2}$/.test(perros)) {

                  msg("El campo 'número de niños' es obligatorio", 5000);
                  return false;

            }

            else if ( !politicaDatos ) {

                  msg("Debes aceptar la política de datos");
                  return false;

            }
            
            else {
                  return true;
            }
      }
}



function msg(par1, par2 = 2000) {

      document.getElementById('mensaje').innerHTML = par1;

      document.getElementById('alerta').classList.add('visible');

      setTimeout( function(){
            document.getElementById('alerta').classList.remove('visible');
      }, par2);

}
```

```html
<form action="envia.php" role="form" method="POST" id="formulario" onsubmit="return validacion()">

                    <div class= "envoltorioContacto">

                    <div class="izquierda">

                        <div class="Nombre"> 

                            <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" id="campoNombre">

                        </div>

                        <div class="Email"> 

                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="campoEmail">

                        </div>

                         <div class="Telefono"> 

                            <input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" id="campoTelefono">

                        </div>

                        

                    </div>

                    <div class = "derecha">

                        <div class="Adultos"> 

                            <input type="number" name="adultos" placeholder="Nº de adultos..." id="numeroAdultos">

                        </div>

                        <div class="infantes"> 

                            <input type="number" name="infantes" placeholder="Menores de 7 años" id="numeroInfantes">

                        </div>

                        <div class="total"> 

                            <input type="number" name="total" placeholder="Nº total personas (inc. bebés)" id="totalPersonas">

                        </div>

                        <div class="perros"> 

                            <input type="number" name="perros" placeholder="Nº de perros" id="numeroPerros">

                        </div>


                    </div>

            </div>

            <div id="message">

                    <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje..." id="campoMensaje"></textarea>

            </div>

            <div class="datedropper">


                <div>
                    
                    <input class="fecha" name="fechaEntrada" type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada (dd/mm/aa)" id="fechaEnt">

                </div>
                
                <div>
                    
                    <input class="fecha" name="fechaSalida" type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida (dd/mm/aa)" id="fechaSal">

                </div>



            </div>

            <div id="politicaDatos"><input type="checkbox" id="politica"><p> Acepto la <a href="politica/politicadatos.html" data-numero="uno" target="_blank">política de privacidad.</a></p></div>

            <div class="contenedorbotonEnvio">

                    <div><input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="botonEnvio"></div>

            </div>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_POST['enviar']) {

if (mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header)) {

echo "<script language='javascript'>
alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias por contactar con nosotros.');
</script>";
} else {
    echo 'Falló el envio';
}
```

}

Esa validación está mal hecha. En caso que el índice `enviar` no exista no es interpretado por las condicionales de PHP, en pocas palabras, no se usa de igual forma que en Javascript, que `UNDEFINED o NULL` son interpretados como `false` en JS.

Tienes que utilizar `empty()` eso si te regresa un boolean
Puedes revisar la documentación de [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) o de igual forma [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) Aunque se utilizan para cosas distintas.

Aquí encuentras un poco más de información [empty() vs isset() vs is_null()](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/)

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['enviar'] ) ) {

if ( mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header) ) {

echo "<script language='javascript'>
alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias por contactar con nosotros.');
</script>";
} else {
    echo 'Falló el envio';
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Al subirlo al servidor y probarlo, me da el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /homepages/3/d772674175/htdocs/casaRural/envia.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /homepages/3/d772674175/htdocs/casaRural/envia.php on line 6.

Answer (score 1):

#### Uso correcto de variables POST en PHP

Si estas validando con PHP y estas esperando que se realice cierta accion unicamente cuando estas reciviendo el parametro "enviar" mediante POST, lo correcto es que definas las variables después de verificar que lo estés recibiendo. De lo contrario, siempre que no recibas el parámetro enviar, te marcará que $_POST["enviar"] no está definido.

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

$nombre = $_POST('nombre');
    $telefono = $_POST('telefono');
    $email = $_POST('email');
    $adultos = $_POST('adultos');
    $infantes = $_POST('infantes');
    $total= $_POST('total');
    $perros= $_POST('perros');
    $mensaje= $_POST('mensaje');
    $fechaEntrada= $_POST('fechaEntrada');
    $fechaSalida= $_POST('fechaSalida');




// Datos del email
$para = 'elcallejondelagata@gmail.com';
$titulo = 'Solicitud de información';
$header = 'From: ' . $email;
$msjCorreo = "Nombre:".$nombre."\n".
                    "Email: ".$email."\n".
                    "Telefono: ".$telefono."\n".
                    "Numero de adultos: ".$adultos."\n".
                    "Numero de niños: ".$infantes."\n".
                    "Total de personas: ".$total."\n".
                    "Perros: ".$perros."\n".
                    "Fecha de entrada: ".$fechaEntrada."\n".
                    "Fecha de salida: ".$fechaSalida."\n";
if (mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header)) {

    echo "
    alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias por contactar con nosotros.');
    ";
    } else {
        echo 'Falló el envio';
    }
}
```

La funcion `isset()` de PHP sirve para determinar si una variable esta definida dentro del script. Si tu colocas unicamente `$_POST["enviar"]` dentro de la condicion, no te dara el resultado que deseas.

Solucionando lo que vaya a pasar despues de que se haya evaluado todo, al haberlo hecho una redireccion completa a el script PHP `envia.php`, deberas manejar que va a pasar en cada caso, de lo contrario terminaras con una horrible pagina en blanco y en la direccion `www.tusitio.com/envia.php`, puedes incluir un redireccionamiento basico en las cabeceras al terminar la ejecucion del codigo.

`header('Location: http://www.tusitio.com/?correo_enviado');`

Te dejo el link por si te interesa:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

## Regresando JSON de PHP a JavaScript

Para que puedas manejar en tu HTML un control eficiente de lo que ha pasado tendrias que incorporar una solicitud AJAX a tu script PHP. Acomodando el siguiente codigo despues de haber validado los campos.

#### Sin JQuery

```
var data;
data+='nombre='+nombre;
data+='&telefono='+telefono;
data+='&email='+email;
data+='&adultos='+adultos;
data+='&infantes='+ninhos;
data+='&perros='+perros;
data+='&mensaje='+mensaje;
data=+'&fechaEntrada='+entrada;
data+='&fechaSalida='+salida;

httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open('POST', 'http://www.misitio.com/envia.php');
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
    data=JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
    alert(data.cadena);
  }
httpRequest.send(data);
```

#### Con JQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: "www.misitio.com/envia.php",
  data: data,
  type: "post",
  success: function(data){
    data=JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data.cadena);
  }
});
```

#### Regresando informacion desde PHP

```
if (mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header)) {
        echo '{"codigo":"1","cadena":"El correo fue enviado exitosamente."}';
    } else {
        echo '{"codigo":"0","cadena":"Hubo un problema al enviar el correo."}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Luis, muchas gracias por darme una respuesta tan detallada. He copiado y revisado el código PHP pero no llega el correo a gmail (ni al spam).

Comment: Vale, imaginé que pudieses enfrentar un problema así, ¿Has verificado que tengas correctamente configurado en tu cPanel el servicio de correo que 1&1 te proporciona?

Comment: El problema es que no tengo conocimientos de back y pensé que esto iba a ser más sencillo. Intentaré acomodar el código que me has facilitado a ver qué tal. Supongo que el JSON va después de $fechaSalida= $_POST('fechaSalida');
 ¿verdad? EStoy haciendo un curso de PHP en Lynda.com a ver si saco algo en claro... = )

Comment: Gracias por aclararlo, en unos momentos editaré mi respuesta para brindarte un poco más detallada la información e incluir datos que te puedan servir para el correo, ya que al parecer es el mayor problema aquí.

Comment: El JSON va dentro de tu evaluación IF del backend en PHP, para que en tu frontend de HTML y JavaScript puedas mostrarle al usuario si su correo fue enviado o no.

Comment: Es probable que ese sea el problema, les llamaré a ver si me pueden decir.

Comment: Vale, si me puedes notificar si te dieron alguna posible solución te lo agradecería y podría ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Sí en algún sitio he visto que hay que poner el usuario y la contraseña de tu correo en el código. ¿podría ser ese el problema?

Comment: ¿Sabes localizar la configuración de PHP? (php.ini) Intenta localizar el apartado [mail function] y anexa eso a tu pregunta para ver como está configurado.

Comment: He llamado y me dicen que selccione la versión PHP 5.6. Es la única solución que me han dado. Lo he hecho, y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Intenta hacer debug de la aplicacion creando un archivo php nuevo llamado pruebas.php y en el incluye unicamente la funcion mail() con la sentencia if, e intenta cambiar los parametros de la funcion para que trates de hacer que te llegue el correo.

Comment: Eso antes de cambiar a PHP 5.6

Comment: Una cosa que a lo mejor es una pregunta chorra...pero asumo que he de poner enviar(value) y no submit(type)....

Comment: Si hablas de tu HTML, eso es lo de menos, tu sintaxis es correcta, el problema como me lo mencionas esta del lado del servidor con el envío del correo.

Comment: Lo de PHPmailer lo miré anteriormente, pero tuve dificultades para instalar console globalmente en mi mac...así que lo intenté por este medio.

Comment: Dejo este enlace pues parece que la instalacion de coposer en Mac es más compleja debido a la polítca de integridad de Mac: os paso este enlace por si puede ser de ayuda: https://marc.vos.net/howto/phpmailer/

Comment: Hola, disculpa la tardanza cuanto a mi respuesta. Si MAC es tu entorno de desarrollo con sitios web, deberías intentarlo hasta lograrlo, verás la sencación de éxito que se siente. De lo contrario, si tu entorno de desarrollo es en Windows o Linux, podrías emular una máquina virtual y trabajarlo desde ahí mientras empiezas a desenvolverte completamente en éste nuevo entorno.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, no tengo forma de instalar PHPmailer via composer y con la instancia mail() nunca iba a enviarse...siento haberte hecho perder el tiempo. Pensé que con sólo el PHP llegaría.